# Image -> 2d matrix of color values in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Are there any solution of converting any image to the 2d matrix of color values in node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GD bindings library](https://github.com/taggon/node-gd) for the various image manipulations in node.js. To get the color of some pixel GD has `getPixel` method.

Answer (score 6):

Before considering GD or similar, look at Node.js packages like [get-pixels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-pixels) that do the job without any external dependencies.

Building on their default example:

```
    const getPixels = require('get-pixels');
    const src = `test.jpg`;

    getPixels(src, function(err, pixels) {
      if(err) {
        console.log("Bad image path");
        return;
      }

      for (let y = 0; y < pixels.shape[1]; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < pixels.shape[0]; x++) {

          const r = pixels.get(x, y, 0);
          const g = pixels.get(x, y, 1);
          const b = pixels.get(x, y, 2);
          const a = pixels.get(x, y, 3);
          const rgba = `color: rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${a});`;
          console.log(rgba);
        }
      }
    });
```

[This post provides more advanced examples.](https://medium.com/@mackplevine/node-js-get-pixels-getting-pixels-at-specific-sectors-of-an-image-using-ndarray-e6d4cb285d36)